# What is the best way to write a generic httpservletresponsewrapper that handles all special cases of response's contenttype in a large web app?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I am customizing a large COTS content management system  known as [Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Documentation+Home).

Confluence returns many different types of httpservletresponses (text/ascii, image/png, image/jpg, microsoft powerpoint files,  PDF files, etc...).

I have written a [servletfilter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) that attempts to modify all responses sent back to the client by writing out a small set of bytes.  This works well for the most part.  However, I have to continuously check for special cases like powerpoint files, or PDFs, PNGs, etc..  If the user happens to be downloading such content I do not modify the response at all.  Modifying the response breaks stream of powerpoint bytes or PDF bytes that are in the process of being served to the client.  By simply checking for these special cases and not writing out any of my bytes my problem is solved.  But I feel the bigger problem is there could be many many more cases I am not thinking of (perhaps audio and video) or who knows what.  I will have to continue playing the game of checking for these special cases as I learn of them.

I was wondering if there is a smarter way to handle this.

I did a google and I ran into this [example](http://code.google.com/p/common-java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/commonjava/web/servlet/GenericResponseWrapper.java?r=54).

I'm looking for something along the lines of this example, but I was hoping someone could explain to me what's going on behind the scenes and if I can solve this problem in a smarter way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter example is sort of incomplete, but the gist of what it seems to be doing is buffering the entire response in to a byte array, with which you can do whatever you want later. I think the implication is that you might extend this filter, then call getData() after the filter chain fires, and then perform processing.

You don't speak to what you're doing, or why the content type matter, or why "special" content types that you don't care about (that you just pass through) matter.

What you can do, is you could create a registry of content type handlers to classes. Then, as you detect the content type of the outbound request, you can dispatch to the appropriate handler. These handlers can be simply represented as a map of content type -> class name of the handler, with a default pass through "do nothing" handler for any content type that is not registered. You can load that map from a properties file, filter configuration, or a table in the database.

While it may seem attractive to just buffer the entire output stream and then act upon it, I would recommend against it. Imagine the memory pressure if the user is downloading a large (10's to 100's of MB) PDF or video or something else. Perhaps most of your content is appropriate to be buffered, but there may well be some that are not.

Of course your handler can implement many of the portions of the filter chain, and act as a proxy filter, so your handlers can do anything a filter can do.

Also, your filter may interfere with higher order HTTP processing (notably chunk delivery, range support, Etag and caching support, etc.). That stuff can be a pain to have to redo.

Comment: If the response is text/html I can write out my custom bytes (it's a JSON string that will be parsed by java script later in order to perform some GUI related activities).  The content type matters because I simply cannot write out JSON to a PNG,PDF,Powerpoint, MS Word, Excel, audio, video, and the list goes on and on.. Ideally I want a finite list of all content types that can be registered for good.  If I can't get a finite list of content types then I would like to figure out a smarter way of sovling this problem instead of waiting until the next issue.